# recursion permutation string crash

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing a code "recursion permutation of string" in Python 
It crashed after one tree(?) cycle. 
I can not find the reason why. please explain about it.

```
memory = []
memory2 = []

def permutation(s):


if len(s)==1:
    return s


for i,char in enumerate(s):
     returns= permutation(s[:i] + s[i+1:])
     print(returns)
     if returns == None:
         for j in memory:
            memory2.append(s[i] + j)
         memory = []
     memory.append(s[i] + returns)
     print(memory)
 s = "ABC"
 print(permutation(s))
```

After it formed the  memory[cb, bc] 
It should goes to the next for loop. 
but it just end it.

Comment: Can you post what the crash was? What error is getting thrown, and what line is causing it?

Comment: Assuming this is not a copy 'n paste error, you need to fix the indention in your code.

Comment: Also, can you use `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: leaf I'm quite new to programming. can you explain it more ?

Comment: I think part of the issue is that if `len(s)` is larger than zero, this function never returns anything.

Comment: where shoud I put the return for len(s) >0?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forget 'else' in your condition:

```
memory = []
memory2 = []

def permutation(s):
    global memory
    global memory2

    if len(s)==1:
        return s

    for i, char in enumerate(s):
        returns = permutation(s[:i] + s[i+1:])

        if returns == None:
            for j in memory:
                memory2.append(s[i] + j)
            memory = []
        else: # <--- here 
            memory.append(s[i] + returns)

s = "ABC"
permutation(s)
print(memory2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your function like so:

```
def permutations(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return [s]
    result = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(s):
        for perm in permutations(s[:i] + s[i + 1:]):
            result.append(letter + perm)
    return result
```

or use standard library function [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = ["".join(perm) for perm in permutations(s)]
```

both of them return the same result:

```
s = "abc"
print(permutations(s))  # ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```